# Why my asymptote image is rendered like this?

Tags: asymptote

After successful installation of Asymptote, when I execute a sample file why are there horizontal lines in the image (with `pdflatex`) but if I make it as a separate `asy` file and execute `asy file.asy` with `settings.outformat="pdf"` It is rendered well. What is the issue? Here is the tex source code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}[width=10cm,height=10cm]
settings.prc=false;
import three;
draw(unitsphere);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The foo-1.asy code:

```
if(!settings.multipleView) settings.batchView=false;
settings.tex="pdflatex";
defaultfilename="3dintersect-1";
if(settings.render < 0) settings.render=4;
settings.outformat="";
settings.inlineimage=true;
settings.embed=true;
settings.toolbar=false;
viewportmargin=(2,2);


settings.prc=false;
import three;
draw(unitsphere);
size(284.52756pt,284.52756pt,keepAspect=true);
```

Comment: This looks like a bug somewhere; it compiles fine for me. I have two suggestions: 1) If your tex file is named `foo.tex`, try opening `foo-1.asy` and compiling it directly using `asy`. If the problem shows up there, then post the code for `foo-1.asy`; if not, it's a problem with the `asymptote` package. 2) This is a good time to be posting on [the Asymptote help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/), as John Bowman (one of the creators) is actively trying to iron out bugs and irregularities.

Comment: @CharlesStaats can you come for a chat

Comment: Maybe later; my day is about to start.

Comment: Actually, opening foo-1.asy and compiling it directly using asy renders but I am not able to see the image because it exits after executing immediately.

Comment: It works fine for me with miktex, asymptote and winedt setup. Mau be something went wrong with your installation.

Comment: @subham soni: Running `asy foo-1.asy` should produce a file called `foo-1.pdf`. Open `foo-1.pdf` and see what it looks like.

Comment: Nope `asy foo-1.asy` generates the same error :(. noticed just now @CharlesStaats

Comment: Can you show the text of `foo-1.asy`?

Comment: @CharlesStaats please see my edited code

Comment: I saved your code to `3dintersect-1.asy` and ran it, and it worked fine on my machine. Can you tell me what operating system, pdf viewer, and version of Asymptote you are using? (If you don't know the asymptote version, you can get it by running `asy -version` at the command line.)

Comment: This may be a graphic card driver issue. I used to get some of these some times ago (linux support for some cards is rather poor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just came across the following lines in the manual, which seem to address your issue.

> High resolution rendering is done by tiling the image. If your
>   graphics card allows it, the rendering can be made more efficient by
>   increasing the maximum tile size maxtile to your screen dimensions
>   (indicated by maxtile=(0,0). **If your video card generates unwanted
>   black stripes in the output**, try setting the horizontal and vertical
>   components of maxtiles to something less than your screen dimensions.
>
> [emphasis added]

For context, this is found in the description of the `three` module. It's listing the four ways of viewing 3d Asymptote output; this is in number 2 (using `settings.render = n;` to produce rasterized output).

Comment: Could you please look into this question and help me? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429345/asymptote-non-zero-values-for-settings-render?noredirect=1#comment1075166_429345

Comment: I googled and looked at the dictionary, but still don't know what are "horizontal and vertical components of maxtiles". Could any one explain for me?

Comment: `maxtile` is an Asymptote setting. See http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Options.html#Options