# Asymptote - non-zero values for settings.render

Tags: asymptote

For any values greater than zero, I could not produce any figure using `asymptote`. Can someone help me, what the issue is?

I tried the top answer at [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158762/44940). With `settings.render=0` it works fine.
However another example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428715/multi-particle-rendering-using-matlab2tikz/428747#428747) (and also the same above example), with values greater than zero. It does not work, not even for `settings.render=1`.

Comment: Just for curiosity: what happens if you remove the render thingy from the asy file and compile it with `asy -render 4`?

Comment: Still does not work. Same result. I updated asy to 2.44 but still the issue persists.

Comment: There is blink during compilation (sudden open and close of file) occurs when render>0. The same does not occur for render=0

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have run out of ideas and hope that you find someone competent to answer your question.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the support this far.

Comment: Perhaps you'd benefit from looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176539/why-my-asymptote-image-is-rendered-like-this?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the discussion below [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409369/problem-rendering-3d-asymptote-surfaces), and try to draw the attention of O.G. and/or Charles Staats to your question...

Comment: I suggest asking here: https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349

Comment: But here are some things you could add to your question (in either place) to make it easier to help you: 1. What error message / terminal output are you getting? 2. What about if you run with `asy -v` or `asy -vv`? (The `v` is for 'verbose'.) 3. What OS are you using and how exactly did you install asymptote?

Comment: @CharlesStaats: 1. I get the following error from TexMaker: `! LaTeX Error: File `input-particles' not found.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{asypicture}``. However, I do not get any error from terminal. 2. I get the following with `asy -vv` : https://pastebin.com/YLJRh1y4    3. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed the asymptote 2.44 from the sourceforge.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Weird part is `asy` produces blank page for `render.settings` greater than 0.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan : Could you try to install some Debian package, like in my comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347237/compile-locally-asymptote-in-a-texlive-compatible-way . Even it is the necessary package to compile.  Your problem is strange. If it does not work, desinstall asymptote and since a Ubuntu debian package is available, try to install it by apt-get, so that you will have all the necessary libraries. It is an older version but it is worth trying.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I posted the question in sourgeforge as you suggested. But I have not received any help so far. Could you please look into this? https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/da9aadb4/